# How do I check user command history with TIME / Linux?

Tags: bash, centos, redhat

How do I check WHEN did a user issue a command? I can see a command being issued in .bash_history , but I'd like to know WHEN it was issued?
I'm aware of the export HISTTIMEFORMAT='%F %T  command, but that only logs AFTER I've issued the command.

Comment: See this answer: https://askubuntu.com/questions/391082/how-to-see-time-stamps-in-bash-history.  I don't think it is possible to apply time format with a retroactive effect.

Comment: @codeforester you're right, you can't... That's a bit disappointing.

Comment: `.bash_history` is the only place the time *would* be recorded. The shell simply doesn't track that information unless you ask it to.

Comment: Honestly I think it should be enabled by default, would be much more useful for diagnosing which user did what and when as to point fingers to the person who messed up :P .

Answer (score 0):

Do the entry of command in .bash_profile

```
#echo 'export HISTTIMEFORMAT="%d/%m/%y %T "' >> ~/.bash_profile
#source ~/.bash_profile
```

Where,

%d – Day 
%m – Month 
%y – Year 
%T – Time